# How to use Message Queue in Web Crawler?

Tags: architecture, rabbitmq, message-queue

The Web Crawler works with multiple Workers located on different machines, so, it seems that Message Queue as the integration layer should fit very well.

The problem though is that I don't understand how to do it.

Without the MQ architecture looks like following - there's a shared DB, the Worker look up in the DB for the next url to process, process it and updates the DB.

But, how to do it with MQ? Suppose the urls for the site to be processed stored in the DB, should I put all of them in the Message Queue for Workers to consume?

What if there's 100 000 such urls, and 100 such sites? Should I put 100 000 000 objects in the Message Queue at once? Or there should be some sort of back pressure - like - I put let's say 100 urls in the queue and wait until all of it being processed, then put next 100 and so on?

Or, maybe such use case isn't a good fit the Message Queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Message Queue is a good pattern to use when you have workers / background jobs.

But usually you need to use it when latency is important or you have multiple different sources you want to listen (in this case queue is usually faster / better to implement than database access).

Huge advantage is the ability to control the flow, for example using back pressure, as you mentioned.

I don't think it's a problem to keep millions of objects in queue, they are optimized for that. For instance, ActiveMQ has a paging cache.

At the same time, if you use reliable database and you don't need to manage the flow, it's probably fine to just use database.

So it depends on your use case:

- Use Database if your flow is simple, for example just one app that generates URLs to parse.
- Use Message Queue if you have multiple different sources and/or low latency is your goal.